# Class constructor ignores optional fields in React Native, but works as expected in browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, class

I have class like

```
class RegisterDto {
  phone: Nullable<string> = null;
  name?: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

new RegisterDto();
```

The "name" field is optional. If I run this code in the browser console, I get `{phone: null, name: undefined}` as it should. If I run this code in RN I only get `{phone: null}`

Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: When you say: _"If I run this code in the browser console"_ , how are you doing that? TypeScript code won't run in the browser console.

Comment: @NickParsons By removing all types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, if you don't initialize a field then that field is removed in the transpiled class declaration. In your case, your typescript class transpiles to the following JavaScript code, which is what ends up being ran in your ReactNative project:

```js
class RegisterDto {
  constructor() {
    this.phone = null;
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

As there is no `name` field set, you don't see `name` set in the associated JS code that is generated.

On the other hand, when you remove the type annotations from your `class` and run your code in the console, you're now using JavaScript's [public class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) syntax. In this case, when a public class field is not initialized to a value it defaults to `undefined`, unlike with TypeScript where it will strip the initialization of the property altogether.

---

To make your TypeScript code behave in the same way, you can initialize your property to `undefined`:

```js
name?: string = undefined;
```

Now `name` will be defined as an own-property on your instance, and will hold a value of `undefined`.